# PL/SQL ExcelDocumentType document name wrong

Tags: sql, oracle, apache, plsql, mod-plsql

I am using Jason Bennet's ExcelDocumentType document api to create a spreadsheet using pl/sql (http://www.jasonsdevelopercorner.com/?page_id=8). I am displaying the spreadsheet via a DAD (dads.conf). Generating my spreadsheet content via pl/sql is working well however I have a minor issue with the file that is being downloaded in my browser. The issue is relating to the file name.

The last line in my pl/sql procedure is excelReport.displayDocument('TestEmployeeReport.xls');
however when i hit the URL as specified in my dads.conf file the excel file that comes back equal to the URL specified in my dads.conf file.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this so that it displays TestEmployeeReport.xls in the internet browser window?

thanks

Comment: Can post the relevant part of the dads.conf file?

Comment: What is the web server you are using?

Comment: <Location /mytools>
    SetHandler pls_handler
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride None
    PlsqlDatabaseUsername MYUSER
    PlsqlDatabasePassword MYUSERNAME
    PlsqlDatabaseConnectString MYDBNAME
    PlsqlAuthenticationMode Basic
    PlsqlDefaultPage rriviereq.websupport.main
</Location>

Comment: Please add http headers from server response to question text.

Comment: Why you wondering about URL? Is file name proposed by browser same as specified in displayDocument procedure parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that the mime settings are not properly set.

Check the source code for a call to owa_util.mime_header and see if later on some thing similar to

```
htp.p('Content-Disposition: filename="' || document_name || '"');
```

can be found and if the "document_name" has been properly set.